Basic linear algebra - How does $A'BA = I$ imply $AA' = B^{-1}$?
$A'BA = I$, B is symmetric. Why does this imply $AA' = B^{-1}$?
I took my linear algebra course 7 years ago and I've forgotten almost everything. Now I'm reading a paper which presents the following:
$F = (n\times k), B = F'F = (k \times k)$, $A=(k \times k)$, and $G = FA = (n\times k)$. G is orthogonal.
$G'G=(FA)'FA=A'F'FA=A'(F'F)A=A'BA$
The paper says $A'BA=G'G=I$ (because G is orthogonal) implies $AA' = B^{-1}$. How does this work?
P.S. The whole purpose of the above is to solve for $A$ later, which transform $F$ to an orthogonal matrix $G$ of the same dimension. From $F$ to $B$ and then to $A$.
Any help will be appreciated, thanks!!

This is straightforward. $A'BA=I$ implies $AA'BA=A$ and hence, multiplying by $A^{-1}$ from the right, $AA'B=I$, so that $AA'=B^{-1}$.
Note that the assumption $A'BA=I$ implies that both $A$ and $B$ are invertible. It is not needed, that $B$ is symmetric.
